# Python file always runs at C:/Users/User and not in the working directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I'm launching python file in VS Code that for example located at `C:\Users\andre\Desktop\NewFolder\Something.py` or `D:\Pythons\Something.py`

I'm getting `C:\Users\andre` via `os.getcwd()` and not the directory where python script is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code takes the open **folder** as the workspace. So please open the whole folder in VS Code, not just a `.py` file, then VS Code will not be able to find your workspace and will use the computer user directory as the workspace by default. So naturally you get the wrong script path.

**Example:**

*Open the folder as a workspace:*

[image]

*Just open a .py file:*

[image]

*VS Code open folde:*

[image]